# Filling hash of multi-dimensional arrays in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, multidimensional-array

Given three scalars, what is the perl syntax to fill a hash in which one of the scalars is the key, another determines which of two arrays is filled, and the third is appended to one of the arrays? For example:

```
my $weekday = "Monday";
my $kind    = "Good";
my $event   = "Birthday";
```

and given only the scalars and not their particular values, obtained inside a loop, I want a hash like:

```
my %Weekdays = {
      'Monday' => [
                    ["Birthday", "Holiday"],     # The Good array
                    ["Exam", "Workday"]          # The Bad array
                  ]
      'Saturday' => [
                    ["RoadTrip", "Concert", "Movie"],
                    ["Yardwork", "VisitMIL"]
                  ]
}
```

I know how to append a value to an array in a hash, such as if the key is a single array:

```
push( @{ $Weekdays{$weekday} }, $event);
```

Used in a loop, that could give me:

```
%Weekdays = {
        'Monday' => [
                    'Birthday',
                    'Holiday',
                    'Exam',
                    'Workday'
                    ]
}
```

I suppose the hash key is the particular weekday, and the value should be a two dimensional array. I don't know the perl syntax to, say, push Birthday into the hash as element [0][0] of the weekday array, and the next time through the loop, push another event in as [0][1] or [1][0].  Similarly, I don't know the syntax to access same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your variables, I'd write it like this:

```
push @{ $Weekdays{ $weekday }[ $kind eq 'Good' ? 0 : 1 ] }, $event;
```

However, I'd probably just make the Good/Bad specifiers *keys* as well. And given my druthers:

```
use autobox::Core; 
( $Weekdays{ $weekday }{ $kind } ||= [] )->push( $event );
```

Note that the way I've written it here, neither expression cares whether or not an array exists before we start.

Comment: That does the trick, thank you. I also appreciate the idea of using a hash of hashes instead; I will have to refactor some other stuff first, though.

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason that

```
 push @{ $Weekdays{Monday}[0] }, "whatever";
```

isn’t working for you?